# Include both local and server at the same time

Tags: php

I have an include statement in my program:

```
include_once("C:/apache2.2/htdocs/AdminTool/includes/functions.php");
//include_once("/var/www/AdminTool/includes/functions.php");
```

I only use one at a time. In the code above I am using it for my localhost. But if I will run it on server, I have to comment the local one. Because it will cause error.

Is there a way to run them both and if it does not find the file no error is returned. Because it is tiring to change them back and forth and I have many .php files like this.

Kind of like (not an actual code):

```
if (include_once("C:/apache2.2/htdocs/AdminTool/includes/functions.php");)
else (include_once("/var/www/AdminTool/includes/functions.php");)
```

Comment: How about `define('ADMINTOOL_BASEDIR', ...)` in a config file?

Comment: `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/functions.php')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_exists: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

is_dir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Best way to do that is use `dirname(__FILE__)` which gets the directory's full path of the current file in ether unix of windows format. Then we use `realpath()` which conveniently returns false if file does not exist. All you have to do is specify a relative path from that file's directory and put it all together:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/include.php';
if (realpath($path)) {
    include($path);
}
```